# How to remove all duplicate values (under same or different key(s)) from a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, duplicates

I have a dictionary like following:

```
{"A": ["a", "b", "c"],
 "B": ["a", "d", "f"],
 "C": ["i", "i", "j"]}
```

I want to transform it as following:

```
{"A": ["b", "c"],
 "B": ["d", "f"],
 "C": ["j"]}
```

That is, all the duplicate values are removed, no matter they appear inside same key or different keys. How to achieve it efficiently?

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: Count values with `collections.Counter`, then use that to filter each list.

Comment: "all the duplicate values are removed" - why are all "a" removed but not all "i" ?

Comment: @sj95126 understood, updating my question.

Answer (score 2):

This code will remove all duplicates:

```py
from collections import Counter

def remove_all_dupes(d):
    c = Counter()
    for v in d.values():
        c.update(v)

    for k,v in d.items():
        d[k] = [item for item in v if c[item] == 1]
    return d

d = {"A": ["a", "b", "c"],
 "B": ["a", "d", "f"],
 "C": ["i", "i", "j"]}

print(d)
remove_all_dupes(d)
print(d)
```

Output as requested.

I am hoping this is reasonably efficient, ie `O(n)` because it only loops through all the values twice and the lookup to eliminate duplicates should be `O(1)`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
from itertools import chain

d = {"A": ["a", "b", "c"],
     "B": ["a", "d", "f"],
     "C": ["i", "i", "j"]}
new_dic = {}
values = list(chain(*d.values()))
for key, value in d.items():
    new_dic[key] = [x for x in value if values.count(x) == 1]
      
print(new_dic)
```

using dictionary comprehension:

```
new_dic = {key: [x for x in value if list(chain(*d.values())).count(x)==1] for key, value in d.items()}
```

output:

```
{"A": ["b", "c"], "B": ["d", "f"], "C": ["j"]}
```

Comment: This solution suffers from the problem that `.count(x)` has to scan the whole of `values` for every `x`.

Answer (score 2):

This code doesn't use any imports.

```py
data = {"A": ["a", "b", "c"], "B": ["a", "d", "f"], "C": ["i", "i", "j"]}

# vals = []
# for ky in data.keys():
#     vals = vals + data[ky]

vals = sum(data.values(), [])    

dups = set([val for val in vals if vals.count(val) > 1])

data_deduped = {
    ky: [val for val in data[ky] if not val in dups] for ky in data.keys()
}

print(data_deduped)
```

```
Sample Output
{'A': ['b', 'c'], 'B': ['d', 'f'], 'C': ['j']}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pip install more-itertools` and use `flatten` to fastly create a list of all values and count them with `Counter` from `collections`.

```
from more_itertools import flatten
from collections import Counter

def remove_duplicates(d):
    all_values = list(flatten(d.values()))
    count = Counter(all_values)
    filtered_dict = {key: [v for v in value if count[v] == 1] for key, value in d.items()}
    return filtered_dict
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter

d_input = {"A": ["a", "b", "c"], "B": ["a", "d", "f"], "C": ["i", "i", "j"]}
d_correct_answer = {"A": ["b", "c"], "B": ["d", "f"], "C": ["j"]}

# first make a giant list of all lists in dictionary
giant_list = []
for key in d_input:
    partial_list = d_input[key]
    # build a big list of all items
    giant_list.extend(partial_list)
# use counter to find items
counted = Counter(giant_list)
# now build remove list
remove_list = []
for key in counted:
    if counted[key] > 1:
        remove_list.append(key)
# now loop and remove by only adding proper results to new dict
result = {}
for key in d_input:
    partial_list = d_input[key]
    new_partial_list = []
    for item in partial_list:
        if item not in remove_list:
            new_partial_list.append(item)
    result[key] = new_partial_list
print(f'it is {result == d_correct_answer} that this code works')
```

Comment: This solution seems to long and complex for a quite simple problem

Comment: It's just as complex as your solution, just not hidden under the hood. I wrote it out step by step in a way that hopefully self documents the thought process.

Comment: I disagree. Your code is take many more lines and is harder to read